# Can a web application in grails be created as Jar and use in other project as dependency

Tags: grails, web

I have a project A which is in `grails`. I need to use project `A` as dependency in my other grails project `B`. Can a jar be created of project `A` and used as dependency in project `B`?

Answer (score 0):

> Can a jar be created of project A and used as dependency in project B?

Yes.  The typical way to do this is by making project A a plugin, but you can bundle any Grails application up as a Jar and reference its classes from any other JVM app, including other Grails applications.